# jQuery add value to closest element in table

Tags: jquery, html

i have a problem. I need to add different values in 2 same classes.
I need to do:
1. When i change dropdown from Test 1,2,3 and 4 the value in text field must be 10, 15 or...values from text input (in real system they are hidden) with id = price-1,2,3 and 4.
2. When i change dropdown from Test 5,6,7, and 8 the values from first dropdown must not change.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" value="10" id="price-1" size="2" />
<input type="text" value="15" id="price-2" size="2"/>
<input type="text" value="20" id="price-3" size="2"/>
<input type="text" value="25" id="price-4" size="2"/>
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select class="drop">
            <option value="1">Test 1</option>
            <option value="2">Test 2</option>
            <option value="3">Test 3</option>
            <option value="4">Test 4</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" class="cost" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <select class="drop">
            <option value="1">Test 5</option>
            <option value="2">Test 6</option>
            <option value="3">Test 7</option>
            <option value="4">Test 8</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" value="" class="cost" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('body').delegate(".drop", "change", function() {
    var end = this.value;
    var price = $('#price-'+ end).val();    
    $('.cost').val(price);

});
```

Here is jsFiddler: [JSFIDDLER](http://jsfiddle.net/PLJ5H/3/)

Edit: Found the solution!

New JS:

```
$('body').delegate(".drop", "change", function() {
    var end = this.value;
    var price = $('#price-'+ end).val();    
    var new_cost = $(this).parents('tr').find('.cost');
    $(new_cost).val(price);

});
```

Comment: Hi, if you have solved your problem please add the solution as an answer

Comment: You should be using `closest` instead of `parents`. Also `delegate` is deprecated. You should consider updating your jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

JS:

```
$('body').delegate(".drop", "change", function() {
   var end = this.value;
   var price = $('#price-'+ end).val();    
   var new_cost = $(this).parents('tr').find('.cost');
   $(new_cost).val(price);
});
```